# How to add a border next to an image?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs within a larger div. The first one has an image, the second has text.

In the first div, there is a border **below** the image currently.

http://jsfiddle.net/8f3arq2y/

```css
#newsfeed_header {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 98%;
    position: relative;
}
#nf_image:after {
    content: " ";
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
    display: block;
}
#nf_text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsfeed_header">
    <div id="nf_image">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/35x35" />
    </div>
    <div id="nf_text">Read the latest</div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

However I'd like the border to be **next** to the image, how can I do that?

```
|<img>__________________|
|text                   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it, also works with dynamic image size.

```
#nf_image {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#nf_image img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#nf_image:after {
    display: table-cell;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

<kbd>**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u7ddvqyy/)**</kbd>

```css
#newsfeed_header {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 98%;
    position: relative;
}
#nf_image {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#nf_image img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#nf_image:after {
    display: table-cell;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
#nf_text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsfeed_header">
    <div id="nf_image">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/35x35" />
    </div>
    <div id="nf_text">Read the latest</div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an empty div below the image to do this:

```css
#newsfeedheader{
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 98%;
    position: relative;
}

#border {
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    z-index: -10;
}

#nf_text{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
 <div id="newsfeed_header">
     <div id="nf_image"><img src="http://www.pixelsquish.com/wp-content/gallery/random-impulses/the-arch-jumpers.jpg" height="105" /></div>
     <div id="border"></div>
     <div id="nf_text">Read the latest</div>
     <br/>
</div>
```

You give the div a negative top margin and a negative z-index so that it appears behind the image. That way the border you put on the div appears to be next to the image.

Comment: I like the idea, but it doesn't do it. The border is still visible through the image. It's harder to tell with the random image I chose (that's not the image I'm actually using - the real one has a white bottom so the border is clear)

Comment: I edited the code so it's clearer that the div is behind the image.

Comment: I appreciate that. I was saying that on my screen with my local code, it was appearing as a strikethrough.

Comment: Is it appearing on top of the image in the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!

I added a margin-left equal to the width of the image to the :after block. The bottom border now only starts immediately after the image.